# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: RNViewOverflow was not found in this UIManager

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native (with Expo) to develop an app, but I'm having trouble with something. On iOS it works fine but on Android I get this error:

[image]

Does this swiper component not work with Android?

I have installed react-native-view-overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed your question while dealing with the same problem and found this on the react-native-deck-swiper GH page https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper/issues/218

Apparently what you need to do (and worked 100% for me), is just add the following in your Swiper component:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

...
<Swiper
  ...props
  useViewOverflow={Platform.OS === 'ios'}
/>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that! I think I also had to downgrade the Deck Swiper version, so if anyone has this problem, and this solution doesn't work, try downgrading 1 or 2 versions

Answer (score -1):

It won't work on Android because it needs to be link as you are using the expo so it's not possible.
https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow#manual-installation

**Note:** You can eject the project than can run it.

For more information please check the issue
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1843

Comment: One can easily run into this error without using Expo, to be clear. Hence the confused "what"